# Problem with plotting a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, matlab

I have problem with plotting an differential equation that is as following:

$$
\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} + \pi y e^{x/3}\big(2\frac{dy}{dx} \sin(\pi x) + \pi y\cos(\pi x)\big)=\frac{y}{9}
$$

where the beginning values are $y(0)=1$ and $\frac{dy}{dx}(0)=-\frac{1}{3}$.

What I have done first is to re-write this differential equation (a second order differential equation) in two 1st order differential equations using $u_1=y$ and $u_2=\frac{dy}{dx}$ as following:

$$
\frac{du_1}{dx}=u_2
$$
$$
\frac{du_2}{dx}=\frac{u_1}{9}-\pi u_1 e^{x/3}\big(2 u_2\sin(\pi x)+\pi u_1\cos(\pi x)\big)
$$

If the equations are unclear, can someone please format them so they look better for better understanding. Thanks in advance.

I wanted to solve the equation by the help of RK4 (Runge-Kutta 4th order) and plot the solution in MATLAB. My MATLAB codes are as follows:

```
xend = 2.6; %The endpoint
h = 0.2; %Stage between two consecutive x-points
x = 0; %The startpoint
u = [1 -1/3]; %The beginning values for the 1st order equations
X = x; %Matrix in which I save all my x-values
U = u; %Matix in which I save all my y-values
while x<xend-h/2
    f1 = RK4(x,u);
    f2 = RK4(x+h/2,u+h*f1/2);
    f3 = RK4(x+h/2,u+h*f2/2);
    f4 = RK4(x+h,u+h*f3);
    u = u + h*(f1+f2/2+f3/2+f4)/6;
    x = x + h;
    X = [X;x];
    U = [U;u];
end
plot(X,U); %Plot the solution
```

And here follows the codes for `RK4`:

```
function fp = RK4(x,u)
    fp = [u(2) u(1)/9-pi*u(1)*exp(x/3)*(2*u(2)*sin(pi*x)+pi*u(1)*cos(pi*x))];
end
```

And the plot that I get by this equation is on the link below:

[image]

Can somebody please explain why I get a bad graph? I tried so much that I could, but I couldn't find anything.

Thanks in advance for helping me figure out with this!

Comment: Well, basically, your graph is not that bad. If it's known that solutions of this equation grow unboundedly and exponentially fast, MATLAB plotter tried to do it's best to show such nasty fast growing function. If you want to see any details, you just have to stick to very small intervals of time. Try to take $\lbrack 0, 0.4 \rbrack$ for example and check is it already fast-growing at it or not.

Comment: @Evgeny: But do you see something wrong with my MATLAB codes or something with my equations as described above? Have I done something wrong when it comes to those pieces? Please give your opinion about it.

I tried the intervall $[0, 0.4]$ and the graph looked more "normal". But then how would I describe the intervall $[0, 2.6]$ theoretically? What exactly would the graph represent when I am trying to solve the differential equation for that intervall?

Thanks for response in advance!

Comment: Well, I don't see anything wrong with your MATLAB code (except naming of functions and the fact that it's usually better to reuse already implemented numerical methods than reinvent and reimplement them by yourself). All I can say about the solution that you're study is that it grows very, very fast. What this means in terms of your system is subject of your interpretation, because I don't know what do these quantities mean. It's ok to have such wildly growing solutions because even simple equation $x' = ax$ has solutions that grow exponentially fast (of course, because they are exponents).

Comment: @Evgeny, the reason that I implemented RK4 on my own hand was to compare different solutions to the differential equation above when I choose the stage h between two consecutive x-points. With ODE23 or ODE45 (as you might have thought on them when recommending me using already implemented numerical methods) I would not be able to manipulate the length of the stage h between two consecutive points.

But anyway, I think I might have understand. Thanks for your responses to me!

Last question: have I written the 2nd order differential equation to two 1st order differential equations correctly?

Comment: You rewrote it right, be sure :)